# WinForms. How to make DataGridView to write cell value when use BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingnavigator

I have WinForms DataGridView and BindingNavigator on the From bind to the same BindingSource.

When user enter text into a cell of DataGridView (cell text editor is visible) and press "Move next" in BindingNavigator, 
it is assumed that the grid close cell text editor, text should be written in the DataTable Field and record end edit.

But the grid simply ignore the entered text, and returns the old value in to the cell.

Is it possible make grid to write the entered value when navigating through BindingNavigator?

Comment: please, supply some code with reproducible example.

Comment: There are no code. All are performed at design time in properties window. On the From DataGridView, BindingNavigator, BindingSource. BindingSource is bind to any simple DataTable.
DataGridView and BindingNavigator is bind to BindingSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. All you need is to set the [`CausesValidation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.CausesValidation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property of the [`BindingNavigator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx) class to `true`.

Note that this property is `false` by default and also is hidden by the `BindingNavigator` base class `ToolStrip`, so you cannot do that at design time (also the documentation of the property is misleading). But you can do that via code (for instance, inside your form `Load` event):

```
this.bindingNavigator.CausesValidation = true;
```